# Broken "if" statement in JavaScript code…

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to run this code and everything seems to be working except the if statement. Even though there is a match but it still does not display the correct answer as shown in the code but instead displays the code in else statement.

```js
var colors = [
  "rgb(255,0,0)",
  "rgb(255,255,0)",
  "rgb(0,255,0)",
  "rgb(0,255,255)",
  "rgb(0,0,255)",
  "rgb(255,0,255)"
]

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = colors[3];
var colorDisplay = document.querySelector("#colorDisplay");

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;


for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  //add initial colors to squares
  squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
  //add event listener
  squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    //get color of picked square
    var clickedColor = this.style.background;
    //compare to the pickedColor
    console.log(clickedColor);
    if (clickedColor === pickedColor) {
      alert("COORREECCTT");
    } else {
      alert("WRROONGG!!");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #232323;
}

.square {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: purple;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
}

#container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> Color Game</h1>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is why it's generally a bad idea to mix presentation and data. A better approach would be to attach the click handler only to the correct div and not all of them.

Comment: As the answer below suggests you were doing `'rgb(0, 255, 255)' === 'rgb(0,255,255)'`. Could have been a simple catch if you had included `pickedColor` along side `clickedColor` console.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var colors = [
  "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
  "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
  "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
  "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
]

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = colors[3];
var colorDisplay = document.querySelector("#colorDisplay");

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;


for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  //add initial colors to squares
  squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
  //add event listener
  squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    //get color of picked square
    var clickedColor = this.style.background;
    //compare to the pickedColor
    console.log(clickedColor);
    if (clickedColor === pickedColor) {
      alert("COORREECCTT");
    } else {
      alert("WRROONGG!!");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #232323;
}

.square {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: purple;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
}

#container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> Color Game</h1>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
var colors = [
  "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
  "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
  "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
  "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
]
```

I just added blank..

Comment: where did you add the blank? @Young Kyun Jin

Comment: @Zack Your typing => `rgb(255,0,0);`  My typing => `rgb(255, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

In the if condition you are comparing the two different strings. When you apply this color in `rgb()` format, the browser formats it with spaces between the color arguments.

You gave: `rgb(0,255,0)` 
In browser: `rgb(0, 255, 0)`

So, you need to add spaces in your `colors` array. Change your colors array to this,

```
var colors = [
  "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
  "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
  "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
  "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
]
```